# atmosphere + spring + autowired problems

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, atmosphere

I am developing a web app and trying to integrate a chat (for now). I am using Spring and Atmosphere to do this. 
I managed to get the chat working, but now I seem to have run into a problem. 
I am using the @ManagedService in a separate servlet (similar to the atmosphere-chat-multiroom example) and now I need to access to a bean that is inside the spring application. For the rest of the servlets that I am using, this works flawlessly, but I am at a dead end when it comes to doind this in Atmosphere ManagedService, the service is always returned as null.

Does anyone have any clue as to what I can do?

```
@ManagedService(path = "{room: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*}")
@Singleton
public class ChatRoom {
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChatRoom.class);

private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> users = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
private String chatroomName;
private String mappedPath;
private BroadcasterFactory factory;
@Autowired
IFriendsServices friendServices;

@Message(encoders = { JacksonEncoder.class }, decoders = { UserDecoder.class })
public void onPrivateMessage(ChatUserMessageDTO user) throws IOException {
    String userUUID = users.get(user.getUser());
    friendServices.createChatMessage(user.getUser(), user.getSource(), user.getMessage());
    if (userUUID != null) {
        AtmosphereResource r = AtmosphereResourceFactory.getDefault().find(userUUID);
        if (r != null) {
            ChatProtocolMessageDTO m = new ChatProtocolMessageDTO(user.getSource(), user.getMessage(),
                    users.keySet(), factory.lookupAll());
            factory.lookup(mappedPath).broadcast(m, r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could show us your code.

Comment: What are the annotations of rest of the servlets and the ManagedService?

Comment: the atmosphere managedservice has only the managedService and Singleton. The other ones usually only have Controller

Comment: added some code. The friendServices is returned as null

Comment: Spring won't inject dependency into classes that are not spring components. Annotate your ManagedService with @Service too.

Comment: @cy3er, unfortunetly I already tried that.

Comment: Then worst case you can implement an ApplicationContextAware class with a static getContext method and get the bean directly from the context.

Comment: Delegate the @ManagedService creation to Spring, as described https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Configuring-Atmosphere's-Classes-Creation-and-Injection

Comment: @jfarcand, i have tried that also. still not working with the autowire.

Comment: Annotate your class with @Configurable and follow the instructions here: http://www.olivergierke.de/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/

Comment: You are going to have to wire the IFriendsService yourself. If you create a Singleton class that ApplicationContext Aware, you can get any Spring configured bean (using a lazy initialization approach).

Answer (score 0):

hello i find vary interesting thing when i was digging in spring . for non spring managed classes follow following 2 steps to access properties using autowire

```
public class ChatRoom extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport{ 

and then use @Autowire
```